# documents downloads and other folders missing from home folder in This PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1809

When I open File Explorer and go to my home folder, I do not see many folders like Documents, Downloads, Music, Video, etc... The folders do exist -- like if I go to `C:\Users\nacho\Downloads` but they do not show in the home folder view.

I've followed many online articles that change registry settings to bring them back and it works, they come back, but they disappear again after reboot.

This is happening on both of my Windows 10 machines -- one running home and one running pro.

- Windows 10 Home version 1803 build 17134.472
- Windows 10 Pro version 1809 build 17763.195

[image]

Comment: Just to double-check, did you already configure those machines to [Show all folders](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7078-turn-off-show-all-folders-windows-10-navigation-pane.html)?

Comment: Yes. But that changes what shows on the left, not the right.

Comment: Well, it *should* affect both of them in the same manner.  In your screenshot, you don't have your `nacho` folder expanded on the left, so we can't see if those icons appear *there* but not on the right-hand side.

Comment: Updated picture.

Comment: So, it actually *does* show the same folders in both places, and the ones you seek are missing.  It sounds like a custom option within your configuration.  Also, can you please edit your question to include the appropriate [Windows 10 version and OS build number](https://www.howtogeek.com/236195/how-to-find-out-which-build-and-version-of-windows-10-you-have/) that you are currently using?  You added different tags for version 1803 *and* 1809.

Comment: I am having this problem on both versions. I will add build information.